# How to Push Android project to Github?

Tags: android, github

I'm new to Github, I want to push my android application to Github and save it there.

I'm using the Github application for MAC, I simply drag the project folder to the github application, but I'm not getting all my files.

there is "No committees yet" and when I'm not able to push the project, when I press push it shows an error " Failed to get HEAD"

Thank's for making this clear for me

Comment: Are you using Android-Studio or Eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps to push your project to GitHub.

Hope this will helps you

**Step 1 :** You first need to create account on [github](https://github.com/join)

**Step 2 :** If you already have github account then create repository for your project on github.

**Step 3 :** Clone github repository to your local machine using command

```
git clone <repository-clone-url>
```

**Step 4 :** Add your project files to your clone repository on your local machine

**Step 5 :** Add your files to your stage area

**Step 6 :** Commit stage files

**Step 7 :** Push changes back to your github repository

If you need more information then visit

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

If you are using **eclipse** then there is a plugin [eGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/) is available for same.

Here is complete eGit Tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html

Answer (score 2):

I use git for Windows which is an extremely simple tool. It lets you do all the basics.

https://windows.github.com/

There are instructions on the website. And also there is a Mac version.